# how to prevent Lines from being deleted in a paragraph (Javascript Replace Regex )

Tags: javascript, regex

Please take a look at this (regex101) 
[regex link](https://www.regex101.com/r/kP1uN9/1)

```
var t = $('#text').text();
$('#cvText').html(t.replace(/\b([A-z']+)\b/ig, '<a href="#">$1</a>')).show();
```

Here's the [jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/un2ttc53/1/)

I am using this to capture all words along with apostrophes.
But this is also deleting new lines in a paragraph, which i want to preserve.

How can i do this?

Thx!

Comment: No, it does not match any newlines. Also, you need to use `/\b([A-Z']+)\b/gi`, not `[A-z]`, but `[A-Z]`.

Comment: how to detect and prevent the new lines from being deleted?

Comment: Try `var t = $('#text').html(); $('#cvText').html(t.replace(/\b([A-Z']+)(?![^<>]*>)\b/ig, '<a href="#">$1</a>')).show();`.

Comment: no use, still the same.

Comment: You need to post a fiddle showing the issue. Create a snippet inside the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```js
$('#btn').on('click',function(e){
 var t = $('#text').text();
    console.log(t);
 $('#cvText').html(nl2br(t.replace(/\b([A-Z']+)\b/ig, '<a href="#">$1</a>'))).show();
});

function nl2br (str) {   
    return (str + '').replace(/([^>\r\n]?)(\r\n|\n\r|\r|\n)/g, '$1<br />$2');
}
```

```css
div{ padding:10px; margin:10px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:16px; line-height:30px; overflow-y:scroll }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id='text' style="width:500px; height:350px;">
The young woman, is known as the bride and she usually has two or more bridesmaids to hold her train. Her partner is called the groom and he is accompanied by the best man, who is usually his best friend. His main tasks are to get his friend to the ceremony sober and on time; to look after the ring(s); and to give a humorous speech later on, which is often designed to gently embarrass his friend.

Traditionally the principal men wear red carnations in their buttonholes, while the rest wear white ones. At the beginning of the church ceremony it is customary for the young woman's father to walk her down the aisle, to the accompaniment of organ music. The central, most important part of the ceremony is when the couple exchange their wedding vows.

At the end of the ceremony the guests leave while the couple and their witnesses sign the marriage register. When the couple come out of the ceremony, the guests often throw confetti (small pieces of coloured paper) at them. Then the couple together with their guests go to the reception. This can be held in a hotel, or sometimes in a marquee (a large tent) in a large garden. In the evening the young couple disappear to get changed into their going away clothes, before setting off for their honeymoon.
</textarea>
<br /><br /> 
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Convert" />

<div id="cvText" style="border:1px solid #000; width:500px; hei1ght:350px; display:none;"></div>
```

The `nl2br` function will insert `<br />` or `<br>` before all newlines (`\r\n`, `\n\r`, `\n` and `\r`).

The core of the function is `.replace(/([^>\r\n]?)(\r\n|\n\r|\r|\n)/g, '$1<br />$2');`. The regex matches and captures into group 1 one optional symbol that is not a `>` or `\r`, or `\n`. Then, it matches 1 single linebreak and captures it into Group 2. The replacement consists of the first capture group, the `<br />` and the second captured text (a linebreak).

See the [regex in action at regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/bJ4tT0/1).

Comment: It would be really nice if you can explain a little? Thx!